# Magento: getting attribute values in cart

Tags: magento, attributes, cart

This is my first project in Magento and Im having a problem trying to get the attribute values for my shopping cart items. What I have now doesnt display anything. I have 3 basic attributes (width, height, depth) and one configurable attribute (fabric). This is what I have in default.phtml for the checkout items:

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());

echo $_product->getWidth();
echo $_product->getHeight();
echo $_product->getDepth();

echo $_product->getAttributeText('fabric');
```

I would appreciate it if someone were able to tell me how to get this to work. Thanks.

Comment: does var_dump($_product) display anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
      echo  $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you added your attributes, you gave them an attribute code, lowercase and underscores only. (Catalog > Attributes > Manage attributes, attribute code is normally listed on the left). Assuming you named them something like their description, then....

```
echo $_product->getData('width');
echo $_product->getData('height');
echo $_product->getData('depth');
```

Answer (score 0):

For drop down attribute type getting values in cart can be done by following code:

`echo nl2br($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('fabric')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product));`

fabric is attribute code.You can use your attribute code here.